# Possible causes of loss of electrical contact between PCB traces and male USB Type A connector pins soldered to PCB?

Tags: usb, mechanical, flux

I have a problem that I've been embarrassingly working on for months and unable to completely solve.  I'm a hobbyist and I have a simple PCB with a male USB Type A connector soldered to it: some of my boards work ok and some only see the power LED light up when I jiggle the connector around (boards are from the same batch).  At this point, I am nearly positive it's a mechanical and not a circuit problem, but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong and am seeking suggestions.  I've tried different female ends (i.e., different cables, USB hubs, etc).  I've tried different kinds of male Type A connectors soldered to the board (surface mount, through-hole, etc), with the through-hole connectors being the least problematic, but still some of my through-hole-type-A boards exhibit the problem (some don't).

Could it be rosin solder flux residue on the Type A contacts that result from me trying to clean off rosin solder flux on the PCB using a rubbing alcohol bath?  The boards look clean but I'm wondering if just enough residue is being left on the USB contacts within the connector to be causing me problems.  It seems far fetched, but other than this, I can't think of what else it could be -- I'm about out of ideas.

**EDIT**: When the problem exhibits itself, I see 0V when I put a voltmeter between the 5V and GND pins on the Type A connector.

Comment: Pins connecting to planes are harder to solder, because the bulk copper in the plane thermally loads the pad you are trying to heat.  The high heat capacity of the plane, and the large effective trace width, are both important.  You probably are getting cold solder joints on these connections (the connector pin is hot enough for the solder to flow, but the PCB pad isn't).

Comment: The point where connectors (especially overhanging ones) attach to boards can indeed be a notorious mechanical failure point.  But cheap USB connectors can also be unreliable.  The problem is probably not going to be flux residue.  It's not out of the question that the board is flexing and disturbing a loose connection elsewhere - do you have any QFN or BGA ICs?  Or even a TQFP?  Inspect the solder joints under high magnification.  See if you can find a mechanical action more consistent than wiggling which consistently causes the problem.

Comment: Ben, thanks.  I'm getting no voltage with a voltmeter between the 5V and GND pins, so that would rule out a cold solder joint, correct?

Comment: Chris, the only IC is the LDO voltage regulator (3.3V), which is in a SOT-89-5 package. Your board flex comment is interesting, but I think if board flex is the problem, it must be shorting 5V and GND together, because there's 0V with a voltmeter between the USB 5V and USB GND pins.

Comment: How do you know that is a short and not an open circuit in the feed to one of those nodes from the host or charger?  Can you plug it in through one of those USB current meters?  If it's a short leading to shutdown, presumably the meter itself would loose power, while if it's an open the current would drop to zero but the meter would remain on.

Comment: Could you post some pictures of how does it all look?

Comment: check the continuity through the connector of the 5V and GND lines

Comment: Picture here: https://imgur.com/a/w5HfO
U2 is an unpopulated ESD supressor for D+/D-.
Nothing on the backside of this 2-layer board other than a ground plane and the 4-pin header rows that you see on each side.
Only purpose of this board is for the 3.3V power accessible via the header pin.

Comment: So, you are using some SuperSpeed extender cable (which are not USB-legal). What is on the other end of this extender cable?Did you try to plug your dongle into a regular PC port or regular hub port?

Comment: And what is D1? Polarity?

Comment: Ali, yes, I have.  Not all my boards act the same, some are less consistent than others.  But, for the one sitting in front of me right now, the behavior I see is the same if I plug it into the hub on my desk (goes to PC) or the extension cable (goes to wall charger).  The behavior with both I observe is: If I push the device fully into the female connector, it does not power up (other than a brief  LED flash).  If I pull it out a few mm  (so that it's not fully pushed in anymore), suddenly it powers up and stays on if I leave it alone.  D1 and D2 are unidirectional TVS diodes.

Comment: You must got some cheap Chinese bootleg USB connectors with improper recession of contacts then. Before the USB 3.0 was settled with exact mechanical construction, there were very odd USB 3.0 receptacles who wouldn't make much of contacts with a plug. Now there are probably several billion of USB cables/devices/flashdrives, and they all work just fine. Check all dimensions of your connectors and compare with drawings in USB specifications.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  It's a CUI UP2-AH-1-TH.  This is my third connector, which so far is the best of the three.  The previous one was Molex and I think the first was TE, but both those were surface mount pins and not through-hole pins.  So I guess I'll try a fourth: a Molex through-hole, unless someone here recommends to me a certain manufacturer or part number other than Molex.

Comment: By the way, these are USB 2.0 connectors I'm using on my board.  Both the extension cable and the hub are USB 3.0.  I was under the impression there should be zero issue with plugging USB 2.0 stuff into USB 3.0 receptacles, but your comments make me realize I should point this out.  Should I try a USB 3.0 connector instead?